# Angular 7 : Data looks empty

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to achieve something that looks simple but ...

I want to retrieve some data in a table and to initiate an object with them. The data are the details of my class Conducteur. When I use the input button, I want to display the details or a message if the Conducteur doesn't exist.

Then I have three important parts :
the service :

```
/** Récupérer un conducteur par numéro de carte. Non trouvé: erreur 404 */
  getConducteur(cardNumber: string): Observable<Conducteur> {
    const url = `${this.conducteursUrl}/?cardNumber=${cardNumber}`;
    return this.http.get<Conducteur>(url).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Conducteur>(`getConducteur cardNumber=${cardNumber}`))
    );
}
```

The component.ts file :

```
conducteur: Conducteur;

  constructor(private conducteurService: ConducteurService) { }

  getConducteur(cardNumber: string): void{
    this.conducteurService.getConducteur(cardNumber)
      .subscribe(conducteur => this.conducteur = conducteur);
  }
```

And the html file :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputNumCarte">Numéro de carte de conducteur</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumCarte" 
      aria-describedby="numCarte" placeholder="Saisir numéro"
      #cardNumber>
    <small id="numCarte" class="form-text text-muted">L'utilisation des données est réservée aux plate-formes.</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" 
    (click)="getConducteur(cardNumber.value);
    cardNumber.value=''">Vérifier</button>
</form>
<div *ngIf="conducteur">
  <h2>{{conducteur.cardBearerName | uppercase}}</h2>
  <div><span>Numéro de carte : </span>{{conducteur.cardNumber}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>Prénom :
      <p>{{conducteur.cardBearerFirstname}}</p>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like conducteur isn't initialized but *ngIf display because it exist but he is empty.
Can you help me to find where I miss something ?
Thx

The hhtp request respond this :

```
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "api/conducteurs/?cardNumber=01234567890"
```

The class Conducteur is defined like that :

```
export class Conducteur {
    cardNumber: string;
    cardStatus: string;
    cardBearerName: string;
    cardBearerFirstname: string;
    cardBearerDob: string;
    cardBearerPob: string;
    cardBearerPhoto: string;
}
```

And finally the data who should be initialized :

```
{ cardNumber: "01234567890", cardStatus: "active", cardBearerName: "dupont", cardBearerFirstname: "jérôme", cardBearerDob: "01/01/2000", cardBearerPob: "paris", cardBearerPhoto: "cGhvdG8xCg==" },
```

by the way data are just a mock with In memory web API.

When I try this code :

```
getConducteur(cardNumber: string): void {
this.conducteurService.getConducteur(cardNumber).subscribe(conducteur =>
  {
    if(conducteur)
  {
  this.conducteur = conducteur;
  console.log(this.conducteur);
  }
  else
  this.conducteur=null;
  console.log("conducteur est null !")
  }
  ,(error)=>
  {
  console.log(error);
  });
```

I have this result :
[image]

Comment: Conducteur object is returning from service successfully, right?

Comment: What is your HTTP request returning?

Comment: So the problem is that <div *ngIf="conducteur"> part is displayed altough there is no Conductor?

Comment: It all looks quite ok, seems like the conducteur object doesn't contain what you expect. Can you verify the response from the `http.get`?

Comment: Can you please add your class definitions? It's important to define your classes with or without null property.

Comment: Your problem is that your `conducteur` object **IS** being populated... but it's being populated with an error object. Hence why it's showing as if it's populated.

Comment: Ok that's why all looks fined, because my object is populated with error. Can someone help me to find this error ? Maybe the service ?

Comment: What your's `handleError` returns?

Comment: handleError returns nothing because it works but initialize my Conducteur with null values I think ...

Comment: It's 404ing... `api/conducteurs/?cardNumber=01234567890` isn't being found in your API.

Comment: Right. But as you can see this string IS in the API. Then I'm missing something in the service who doesn't find it. I guess ?

Comment: it looks like my service return an Array of type Object with the conducteur data at index 0. I want it to return a Conducteur to be able to write this.conducteur = conducteur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like there is an issue in returning from an api.
Will you run this code :

```
getConducteur(cardNumber: string): void
{
 this.conducteurService.getConducteur(cardNumber).subscribe(conducteur =>
{
 if(conducteur)
 {
 this.conducteur = conducteur;
 console.log(this.conductteur);
 }
 else
 this.conducteur=null;
}
,(error)=>
{
console.log(error);
});
  }
```

so we can see what api is returning in response or in error(if present).

Comment: good piece of code. I share results in the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution.
My service return an Array with only 1 conducteur at the index of 0.
Then I need to use .map from RxJS like this :

```
getConducteur(cardNumber: string): Observable<Conducteur> {
const url = `${this.conducteursUrl}/?cardNumber=${cardNumber}`;
return this.http.get<Conducteur>(url).pipe(
  map(conducteur => conducteur[0]),
  catchError(this.handleError<Conducteur>(`getConducteur cardNumber=${cardNumber}`))
);
  }
```

Thx for your comments, they help me a lot.